# Не знаю как правильно выкладывать тему вордпресс на хост

Tags: php, html, wordpress

**

### Решение проблемы: часть 1

**
Есть сайт на вордпрессе на хосте, создал новую тему и залил eё на хост в папку с темами, в админовской панели активировал созданную тему и при переходе на сайт показывает такое: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Писал чтобы было так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код `index.php` темы:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> -->
    <title>Тюльпан Трэвэл</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php 
        require_once(get_template_directory_uri() . "/template-parts/hadjj-slider.php");
        require_once(get_template_directory_uri() . "/template-parts/whatneed.php");
        require_once(get_template_directory_uri() . "/template-parts/visa.php");
        require_once(get_template_directory_uri() . "/template-parts/about.php");
        require_once(get_template_directory_uri() . "/template-parts/videoMap-sliders.php"); 
        require_once(get_template_directory_uri() . "/template-parts/reviews.php");
        require_once(get_template_directory_uri() . "/template-parts/tours.php");
    ?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Папка `template-parts`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. получилось так будто я писал `get_header()` и `get_footer()`, а все `require_once()` не сработали, не могу понять почему

P.S. Вывод `get_template_directory_uri()` - `https://tulpantravel.ru/wp-content/themes/tulpan_landing_theme`
P.S.S. Все папки и файлы в теме имеют атрибут `700`
P.S.S.S. Или можете подсказать есть ли какой нибудь лог выполнения php на хостинге чтобы можно было посмотреть ошибки

### Решение проблемы: часть 2

Применив на практике советы, ответ и гуглинг. Я создал в папке темы новую папку `partials` и переместил туда все файлы. После этого вызвал эти файлы в `index.php`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> -->
    <title>Тюльпан Трэвэл</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php 
        get_template_part("partials/hadjj-slider");
        get_template_part("partials/whatneed");
        get_template_part("partials/visa");
        get_template_part("partials/about");
        get_template_part("partials/videoMap-sliders");
        get_template_part("partials/reviews");
        get_template_part("partials/tours");
    ?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Но результат оставался прежним(на странице только `get_header()` и `get_footer()`)
**Супер интересная штука**
Мне в голову пришла одна "извращенская мысль" вставить код из шаблонов прямо в `index.php`, но такое то же не дало никаких результатов, вот[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Тот код с шаблона вообще не отображается на странице или в инспекторе, **хотя я его вставил прямо в `index.php`**

**P.S. Или можете подсказать есть ли какой нибудь лог выполнения php на хостинге чтобы можно было посмотреть ошибки**

Comment: Какая-то костыльная конструкция. Попробуйте заменить на `get_template_part`.

Comment: У вас хостинг бегет судя по скринам. У меня очень много сайтов там и все работает. Проверяйте правильность пути

Comment: @Krya да, это Beget

Comment: Попробуйте get_template_part( 'template-parts/hadjj-slider' )

Comment: Автор, вы неверно вставляете кусок в тему. `get_template_directory_uri()` возвращает URL, а вам нужен путь для `require_once`. Конечно, оно у вас работать не будет. Замените `get_template_directory_uri()` на  `get_template_directory()`.

Comment: @YuriPokhylko `require_once(get_template_directory() . "/template-parts/hadjj-slider.php");` результат прежний

Comment: И пример из моего ответа тоже не работает?

Comment: @YuriPokhylko неа

Comment: @YuriPokhylko тема включается и работает с `get_template_directory() . '/template-parts/hadjj-slider.php'` на локальном сервере openserver. "Ошибка" возникает когда я пытаюсь активировать тему на хостинге

Comment: Это мистика, конечно) Ну пишите в саппорт, что еще можно посоветовать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106407/discussion-between-midnightelf-and-yuri-pokhylko).

Comment: @YuriPokhylko рассмотрите вторую часть вопроса пожалуйста, что думаете?

Comment: Стопэ, а что у вас стоит в Настройки - Чтение - Главная страница? И есть ли файл front-page.php?

Comment: @YuriPokhylko сейчас проверю

Comment: @YuriPokhylko так, что то я долго, в настройки - чтение - главная страница стоит пункт главная, и файла front-page.php нет. Мне нужно перенести содержимое index.php в front-page.php ?

Comment: @MidNightElf Да, тогда заработает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_template_directory_uri()` замените на `get_template_directory()`.

Хотя правильнее здесь использовать `get_template_part`.

```
get_template_part('template-parts/hadjj-slider');
```